# Using the API to get google directory contacts

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps, google-contacts-api, google-api-client

I am a Google Apps customer and want to use the Contact API to search for a user in the company directory.

[image]

I am able to access contacts using for example:

```
feed = gd_client.GetContacts()
```

However the contacts this returns is only a subset of my contacts and is not those in the company directory.

Has anyone had experience of this or give me any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the Domain Shared Contact API instead of the Contact API.  Check this out (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/domain-shared-contacts/)

Try to run the get request against the domain, you should be able to retrieve your directory contacts instead of personal contacts (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/domain-shared-contacts/#Retrieving)

Comment: Emily, how to get it with a user credentials(not Admin) ..?

Answer (score 0):

Try using Query to get result feed. You can specify max results to get in query. This way your result feed will be returned with more contacts in other groups as well.

```
URL FeedURL = new URL("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full");
Query MyQuery = new Query(FeedURL);
MyQuery.setMaxResults(200);
ContactFeed ResultFeed = MyService.query(MyQuery, ContactFeed.class);
```